# what's the best approach the return result or error

Tags: c#

lets say i have this method that call an API and return some results  :

```
    public async Task<List<ClientModel>> GetClients()
    {
        var result = new List<ClientModel>(); 
        try
        {
            results = await myHttpCLient.GetFromJsonAsync<List<ClientModel>>("Api/Clients");

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // Something unexpected went wrong.


        }
        return results;
    }
```

what's the best way to notify the caller in case something went wrong and send back the exception, and if no exception return the expected result, what do you guys use in scenarios like this , i know ref or out may solve this but is this a good design ?

Comment: I would do it exactly like you do. Inside the `catch(Exception e)-Block` I would definitive use a `throw`. Maybe with some custom exception or a standard one. Then the caller can also use a `Try-Catch` to react if something went wrong.

Comment: I think unless you have a custom Exception, just let the `GetClients` method work and fail, and catch the error in the caller method

Comment: @Joaquín you are right. If the inside of the method doesn't react to the exception it does not need a try catch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> what's the best way to notify the caller in case something went wrong and send back the exception, and if no exception return the expected result

Just get rid of the try-catch. This:

```
public async Task<List<ClientModel>> GetClients()
{
    return await myHttpCLient.GetFromJsonAsync<List<ClientModel>>("Api/Clients");
}
```

will do *exactly* what you want:

- If everything was OK, the expected result is returned, but
- if an unexpected error occurred, the execption is *automatically* "bubbled up" to the caller of the method. The .NET Runtime takes care of that, you don't need to do anything.

Of course, *if you want*, you can catch the exception and wrap it in a custom `MyApiCallFailedException`. This, however, is only required if you want to handle it differently from other exceptions at your UI-level global exception handler.

Comment: Alrighty, thanks a lot :)